# A question about Markov chains

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, probability

I'm considering a Markov process with a continuous state space. Let $V(x)$ be a differentiable function, $\Delta t$ a fixed time step, and, at every step, set

$$x_{n+1}= x_n-\alpha \frac{dV}{dx}\Big|_{x=x_n}\Delta t +\beta \xi_n \sqrt{\Delta t}$$

where $\xi_n$ are independent Gaussian variables with unit variance and zero mean. Assuming that $\Delta t $ is small, I'm looking for the stationary distribution.

I found that

$$\rho(x_{n+1}|x_n) = \frac{1}{2\beta \sqrt{\pi \Delta t}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\big(\frac{x_{n+1}-(x_n-\alpha V'(x_n)\Delta t)}{\beta \sqrt{\Delta t}}\big)^2}$$

Letting $\pi(x)$ be the stationary distribution, we then have that

$$\pi(y) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \pi(x)\rho(y|x)dx $$

The detailed balance condition tells us that

$$\pi(y) e^{\big(\frac{y\alpha V'(y) -x\alpha V'(y) +\alpha^2(V'(y))^2\Delta t}{\beta^2}\big)} = \pi(x) e^{\big(\frac{x\alpha V'(x)-y\alpha V'(x) +\alpha^2(V'(x))^2\Delta t}{\beta^2}\big)} $$

At this point it seems like I should use the fact that $\Delta t$ is small, but that’s not clear to me. There's also some helpful information [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/423371/can-we-calculate-the-theoretical-stationary-distribution-from-a-continuous-marko). Maybe you do something along the lines of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1720382/integral-of-product-of-two-normal-distribution-densities) post?

Comment: Check out the [Fokker-Planck equation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fokker–Planck_equation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the evolutionary equation for the distribution function $\rho_n(x)$, let's consider $\overline{f(x_n)}$, where $f(x)$ is an arbitrary smooth function. According to the equation of motion for $x$, taking into account the smallness of $\Delta t$, we have
$$
\overline{f(x_{n+1})} = \overline{f(x_{n})} - \Delta t\ \alpha \ \overline{f'(x_n)V'(x_n)} + \Delta t\ \frac{\beta^2}2\ \overline{f''(x_n)} + o(\Delta t)
$$
The conditions $\overline{\xi_n} = 0$ and $\overline{\xi_n^2} = 1$ were also used in deriving this equality. Now we can write for the distribution function
$$
\rho_{n+1}(x) = \rho_n(x) + \Delta t\left(\alpha \frac{d}{dx}\left(V'(x)\rho_n(x)\right) + \frac{\beta^2}2\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\rho_n(x)\right) + o(\Delta t)
$$
The definition $\overline{f(x_n)} = \int f(x)\rho_n(x) dx$ and integration by parts were used here. There are no boundary terms from integration by parts, because we think that $\rho_n(x)$ and $f(x)$ and their derivatives are zero at infinity. The arbitrariness of the function $f(x)$ was also taken into account. Now we can move on to the Fokker-Planck equation. But we don't need to do this if we are only interested in the stationary distribution. In the case when $\Delta t\to 0$ and $\rho_n(x) = \rho(x)$, we get from the last equation
$$
\alpha V'(x)\rho(x) + \frac{\beta^2}2\rho'(x) = \mbox{const} = 0
$$
And finally
$$
\rho(x) = C e^{-\frac{2\alpha}{\beta^2}V(x)}
$$
where $C$ is the normalization constant. Of course, we need $\alpha V(x)$ to grow to $+\infty$ fast enough when $x\to \infty$.

Comment: Could you explain how you got your first equality for the $\overline{f}$?

Comment: @slowspider I just substituted expression for $x_{n+1}$ into $f(x)$, expanded obtained expression in powers of $\Delta t$ up to the terms proportional to $\Delta t$, and took into account independence of $\xi_n$ and $x_n$ and properties of $xi_n$, its mean value and variance. $x_{n+1}$ is defined through $x_n$ and $\xi_n$, so averaging over $x_{n+1}$ is equivalent to averaging over $x_n$ and $\xi_n$.

Comment: That makes sense. Cool solution!